# Disable command button after one click

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am facing a problem while disabling the command button after one click. I am using action function for this but its not working well don't know why??
can any body please help me to correct my code if i am wrong?

```
  <script>
     function validationRule(){
     savePost();
     }
  </script>
```

vf code:

```
<apex:actionStatus startText="Loading..." stopText="" id="str"> </apex:actionStatus>
               <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:actionFunction name="savePost" action="{!save}" rerender="" status="str" >
                       </apex:actionFunction>
              </apex:actionRegion>
<apex:commandButton image="{!URLFOR($Resource.Test, 'Post_Button.png')}" value="Post"  onclick="validationRule();"  />
```

Please correct me..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're not setting the disabled attribute on the Command Button. Use `this.disabled=true;` or `this.disabled="disabled";`.

Try this:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Account">
    <apex:form >
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validate() {
                // validate code here
                savePost();
            }
        </script>
        <apex:actionfunction name="savePost" action="{!save}" rerender="" status="str" />
        <apex:commandbutton value="Save New Account Value" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'; validate();" />
        <apex:actionstatus startText="Loading..." stopText="" id="str" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```